# Trouble with selection query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table hardest

```
    One                        Two
   apple                      orange
   orange                     grapes 
   banana                     strawberry
   orange                     strawberry
   grapes                     apple
```

Now you can see that i have listed here 5 pairs.
Let me tell you that it is not an ordinary table because in this table fruits' name(apple) are sometime in column one and sometime in column two.

```
And another table Description
name             color  
apple            red
orange           orange
strawberry       pink
banana           yellow
grapes           black
```

Suppose iam banana and i don't want to see the description of fruit which are paired with me.
 **Now can somebody tell me how to display the details of a fruit which has pairing with all of the following in mysql but not with banana: strawberry, grapes, apples.**

I am telling the way to do it which is not supported in mysql.

```
Select * from description 
natural join (select one as name where two='apple' union select two as name where one='apple') as t1 
natural join (select one as name where two='grapes' union select two as name where one='grapes') as t2
natural join (select one as name where two='strawberry' union select two as name where one='strawberry') as t3
MINUS
Select * from description 
natural join (select one as name where two='banana' union select two as name where one='banana') as b6
```

Comment: i dont understand your question at all..?

Comment: what are you not understanding?

Comment: @AnkitGautam: Your recent update to your question adds a requirement that the resultset omit any fruits that are paired with `banana`, citing `MINUS` (which MySQL does not support) as the solution in other RDBMS; there are plenty of examples on this site and others explaining how to effect an equivalent operation in MySQL: indeed, [searching Google for "MySQL MINUS"](http://www.google.com/search?q=MySQL+MINUS) brings up plenty of good results.  Have you had a go at implementing one of these solutions yourself?  Let us know if you encounter any problems.

Comment: I have tried left join but the syntax got me crazy as in various sites left join is given for tables but i am using left join to join two joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Description
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'strawberry'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'strawberry'
) AS t1
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'grapes'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'grapes'
) AS t2
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'apple'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'apple'
) AS t3;
```

---

**UPDATE**

The OP updated the question, adding the constraint that the resultset should exclude any fruit that are paired with `banana`; he then proposed a solution using `WHERE name NOT IN ( SELECT ... )`, but questioned whether an outer join would be more efficient.

First, the query using an outer join:

```
SELECT Description.* FROM Description
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'strawberry'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'strawberry'
) AS t1
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'grapes'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'grapes'
) AS t2
NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'apple'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'apple'
) AS t3
NATURAL LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT One AS name, TRUE As hasBanana FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'banana'
  UNION
  SELECT Two AS name, TRUE As hasBanana FROM hardest WHERE One = 'banana'
) AS t4
WHERE hasBanana IS NULL;
```

With respect to which is more efficient, [this article](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) compares the different approaches.  It states (with respect to `[NOT] IN ( SELECT ... )`:

> Essentially, this is exactly the same plan that `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` uses, despite the fact these plans are executed by the different branches of code and they look different in the results of `EXPLAIN`. The algorithms are in fact the same in fact and the queries complete in same time.

Comment: You haven't even considered the table description

Comment: This is resulting in an empty set

Comment: @AnkitGautam: Was it just because I had `apples` instead of `apple`?  It's working fine at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bfdf/7

Answer (score 0):

I'm cleaning out my answer as the question is mutating away from the original question.

Comment: Have you understand my question

Comment: It gives all fruits that are paired with ANY of apple, strawberry, or grapes - not those that are paired with ALL of them (which is what your question asked for).

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have answer of your own query , You have to use `IN` in place of `=`. Please check query below...

```
select * from hardest,description where 
   (one=name and two IN ('apple' , 'strawberry','grapes')) 
   or 
   (one IN ('apple','strawberry' , 'grapes') and two=name)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the way iam writing is most efficient.If you have any other way more efficient then please write

```
 SELECT * FROM Description 
   NATURAL JOIN (   SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'strawberry'  
     UNION SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'strawberry' ) AS t1
   NATURAL JOIN (   SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'grapes'  
     UNION   SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'grapes' ) AS t2 
   NATURAL JOIN (   SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'apples' 
     UNION   SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'apples' ) AS t3
    where name not in ( SELECT One AS name FROM hardest WHERE Two = 'banana' 
     UNION   SELECT Two AS name FROM hardest WHERE One = 'banana') AS fz );
```

Comment: If anybody is able to do it with left join then please write